# virutal users in postfix

Tags: postfix

I'd like to setup postfix as an MTA for 2 domains, about 10 users each. I'm a bit confused with the documentation. Postfix has so many options for mail delivery. I'd like to have a simple file where I would store all the email addresses (and possibly their corresponding mailboxes). I wouldn't like neither system's passswd file nor mysql to be used for storing email users. What parts of documentation I should be focused on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Postfix Virtual Readme](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) is the mandatory starting point and covers what you are trying to do, then google for more (ie: distro specific instructions, etc).

There are many tutorials out there, all slightly different, most use a database like mysql as backend, but if you understand the postfix concept of maps then using plain text files is no different.

Answer (score 1):

As totaam said, the virtual readme is the place to start, more specifically the [separate domains, non-UNIX accounts example](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox) therein.

The extracted example from the documentation is as follows:

*/etc/postfix/main.cf*:

```
 virtual_mailbox_domains = example.com ...more domains...
 virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts
 virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
 virtual_minimum_uid = 100
 virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
 virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
 virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

*/etc/postfix/vmailbox*:

```
info@example.com    example.com/info
sales@example.com   example.com/sales/
# Comment out the entry below to implement a catch-all.
# @example.com      example.com/catchall
...virtual mailboxes for more domains...
```

*/etc/postfix/virtual*:

```
postmaster@example.com postmaster
```

The documentation is rather self-explanatory, but in the interest of the community, please comment on your resolution to add to the site and answer content.

Answer (score 0):

I would have recommended the [ISPmail tutorial](http://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny) or [VBoxAdm](http://developer.gauner.org/vboxadm/), but since you don't wan't MySQL these links probably won't help you much. Maybe you want to check them out anyway to get a deeper understanding of how Postfix handles Virtual Mailboxes.